# Add on animations for compiz config ? How can I get them?

Tags: compiz

How can I get the add-on animations for the compizconfig settings manager for ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Are you referring to `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`?

Comment: yes, how can i get that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the extra Compiz plugins by opening a terminal and typing:

> `sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`